# If loop is repeating itself when its not needed

Tags: python-3.x

I recently ran into a problem where the code would start repeating itself around line 69. I don't know why this is and any help would be amazing.
Here is the code.

```
import time
import threading
import random


totalviews = 0
videoViews = 0
totallikes = 0
videolikes = 0
totaldislikes = 0
videodislikes = 0
subscribers = 0
videolength = 0
midroles = 0
uploadTimer1 = 0
waitTimer1 = 0
x = 0
comadymins = 0
comadysecs = 0


def timer1():
    global uploadTimer1
    global waitTimer1
    global x
    time.sleep(.75)
    if x == 1:
        print(uploadTimer1, 'mins remaining')
        uploadTimer1 -= 1
        time.sleep(60)
        if uploadTimer1 == 0:
            x = 0


Timer1 = threading.Thread(target=timer1)

print('')
print("you decided to start a youtube channel")
while True:
    time.sleep(1.25)
    print('')
    print('what type of video will you make')
    print('1. comedy')
    print('2. gaming')
    print('3. science')
    print('4. check timer')
    UserInput = input('')
    if UserInput == '1':
        if waitTimer1 == 0:
            comadymins = random.randint(10, 30)
            comadysecs = random.randint(0, 60)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('video length will be', comadymins, ":", comadysecs)
            time.sleep(1)
            if comadymins <= 29 and comadysecs <= 59:
                print('would you like to upload now?')
                time.sleep(.5)
                UserInput = input('')
                if UserInput == 'y':
                    print('video is uploading')
                    print('it will take 4 mins')
                    uploadTimer1 += 4
                    x += 1
                    Timer1.start()
                    waitTimer1 += 1
                else:
                    print('okay')
            if comadymins <= 19 and comadysecs <= 59:
                print('would you like to upload now?')
                time.sleep(.5)
                UserInput = input('')
                if UserInput == 'y':
                    print('video is uploading')
                    print('it will take 4 mins')
                    waitTimer1 += 1
                    uploadTimer1 += 4
                    x += 1
                    Timer1.start()
                else:
                    print('okay')
        else:
            print('you already have a video running')
            time.sleep(1)

    if UserInput == '4':
        print('okay')
        print(uploadTimer1, "mins remaining")
```

any help would be amazing. I am also very new to coding so sorry if the code is messy or not to the average standards. I have only been coding for about a month and do it about 3 hrs a week if you have any recommendations that would be amazing.

Comment: What code exactly is repeating, and what behavior are you expecting? `if` isn't a loop, so it's not clear.

Comment: Your code has the loop `while True:`. This is an infinite loop, because the condition is always true. Furthermore there is no `break` statement or way to exit the loop.

Comment: there might be a problem here though `if comadymins <= 19 and comadysecs <= 59:` , the logic is not right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is, you have the same print data "would you like to upload now?" and two conditional statements that both act the same way.
you have a

```
if comadymins <= 29 and comadysecs <= 59:
```

and a

```
if comadymins <= 19 and comadysecs <= 59:
```

since you have a random number here:

```
comadymins = random.randint(10, 30)
```

something like "11" that is less than "19" and "29" at the same time so both of your conditions will fire and you will see the repeated sentence "would you like to upload now?".
you should work on the logic of your problem.
you may use elif for you second conditional statement to avoid firing in case of first statement was true, or choose a range without overlap.
try this for your first if statement:

```
if 19<comadymins <= 29 and comadysecs <= 59:
```

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you. I understand what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop when you state `while True:`
This will run through all lines underneath it forever.
You could exit this loop by adding a break inside the loop if a certain condition is met.